# Helmholtz Decomposition on $\mathbb{R}^3$ Proof

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, mathematical-physics

I am trying to prove the Helmholtz decomposition theorem which states that given a smooth vector field $\mathbf{F}$, there are a scalar field $\phi$ and a vector field $\mathbf{G}$ such that
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{F}=\nabla \phi +\nabla \times \mathbf{G}
\end{equation}
However, during the proof I questioned myself at a point where we write every such vector field in the Dirac integral way
\begin{equation}
\textbf{F}(\textbf{r})=\int_{V}\textbf{F}(\textbf{r}')\delta(\textbf{r}-\textbf{r}')d\textbf{r}'
\end{equation}
and then use the identity
\begin{equation}
\delta(\textbf{r}-\textbf{r}')=-\frac{1}{4\pi}\nabla{}^2\left(  \frac{1}{|\textbf{r}-\textbf{r}'|}\right)
\end{equation}
in order to get:
\begin{equation}
\textbf{F}(\textbf{r})=\int_{V}\textbf{F}(\textbf{r}')\left[-\frac{1}{4\pi}\nabla{}^2\left(  \frac{1}{|\textbf{r}-\textbf{r}'|}\right) \right]d\textbf{r}'=-\int_{V}\textbf{F}(\textbf{r}')\left[\frac{1}{4\pi}\nabla{}^2\left(  \frac{1}{|\textbf{r}-\textbf{r}'|}\right) \right]d\textbf{r}'
\end{equation}
The question is the following:
What are the conditions that allow the Laplace operator $\nabla{}^2$ to come out of the integral? It has to do something with uniform convergence but I am not sure.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $\psi=\psi(\vec{r}-\vec{r}')$, then
$$
\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial x_i}=\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial (x_i-x_i')}=-\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial x'_i}
$$
This means (let $\nabla'$ be nabla in $\vec{r}'$)
$$
\nabla'^2\frac{1}{|\vec{r}-\vec{r}'|}=-\nabla'\cdot \nabla\frac{1}{|\vec{r}-\vec{r}'|}=\nabla^2 \frac{1}{|\vec{r}-\vec{r}'|}
$$
Now in your integral (by the way in the integral you should have $\nabla'^2$ not $\nabla^2$) you can replace $\nabla'^2$ by $\nabla^2$. This allows you to bring $\nabla^2$ out of the integral since it does not involve any differentiation with respect to the integration variable $\vec{r}'$.

Comment: So the first equation actually shows that $\nabla \psi =-\nabla' \psi$ right?

Comment: Yes exactly. It also shows that $\nabla\cdot \vec{F}(\vec{r}-\vec{r}')=-\nabla'\cdot \vec{F}(\vec{r}-\vec{r}')$ and $\nabla\times \vec{F}(\vec{r}-\vec{r}')=-\nabla'\times \vec{F}(\vec{r}-\vec{r}')$. Pretty much it means the operator $\nabla$ is equal to operator $-\nabla'$ on the subspace of fields (scalar or vector or whatever) depending only on the relative coordinates $\vec{r}-\vec{r}'$.